# neo4j cypher create relation between two nodes based on an attribute String value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a Node with Label Experiment with an attribute called ExperimentName.

This ExperimentName is based on the concatenation of 3 different variables

**"Condition (ExperimentProfile1) Dose"**

**Example :**

```
Control diet (MOA77) LD
Control gavage(MOA66) HD
```

I have another Node called ExperimentMapper
it has 3 attributes : 
- Condition 
- ExperimentProfile
- Dose

I would like to create a Relation between Node **Experiment** and Node **ExperimentMapper** when experimentName is the results of the 3 attributes assembled.

I have tried to use Regex but the query was extremely slow and took forever..

Any help?

This is my cypher but it is taking forever despite me creating indexes

```
MATCH (mxpExperiment:MxpExperiment) OPTIONAL MATCH (otuExperimentMapper:OtuExperimentMapper) 
WHERE  mxpExperiment.name CONTAINS otuExperimentMapper.Condition 
AND mxpExperiment.name CONTAINS otuExperimentMapper.Experiment
AND mxpExperiment.name CONTAINS otuExperimentMapper.dose

CREATE (mxpExperiment)-[:OTU_EXPERIMENT_MAPPER]->(otuExperimentMapper)
RETURN mxpExperiment, otuExperimentMapper
```

Comment: Show how far you have advanced?

Comment: Hi stdob. I have put my cypher in EDIT but as I mentionned it doesn't seem to end..it runs forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to go from the side of the `Experiment Mapper`.

First you need to create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :MxpExperiment(name)
```

Then the query can be as follows:

```
MATCH (otuExperimentMapper:OtuExperimentMapper) 
WITH otuExperimentMapper,
     otuExperimentMapper.Condition  + ' (' +
     otuExperimentMapper.Experiment + ') ' +
     otuExperimentMapper.dose AS name
MATCH (mxpExperiment:MxpExperiment) WHERE mxpExperiment.name = name
MERGE (mxpExperiment)-[:OTU_EXPERIMENT_MAPPER]->(otuExperimentMapper)
RETURN mxpExperiment, otuExperimentMapper
```

Comment: Thanks stdob-- that was helpfull. have you tried using apoc with regex before. I wonder if that would be faster

Comment: @ErEcTuS No, I did not try